yarn not found in docker container after successful build
I navigate to root and run docker build frontend which finds a Dockerfile in the /frontend directory.  Then I enter the docker container using docker exec frontend-1 sh and once in the container npm, node, yarn, all show not found.  It sure looks like the container builds successfully and even runs a yarn command during the build, so I have no idea why I can't manually run yarn build from inside the container.
The real problem I'm trying to solve though, is that I have to rebuild the container everytime I make a change to the React app, when I of course would like to just refresh hot reload.
Dockerfile
# Stage 1: Build the React app
FROM node:16-alpine as build
WORKDIR /app
  
COPY package.json ./
COPY yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install
COPY . ./
RUN yarn build
    
# Stage 2: Serve the React app using Nginx
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]

compose.yaml file
    services:
      web:
        # the application's web service (container) will use an image based on our Dockerfile
        build: .
        # map the internal port 80 to port 8000 on the host
        ports:
          - "8000:80"
        # map the host directory to app (which allows us to see and edit files inside the container)
        volumes:
          - ".:/app:rw"
          - "./data:/data:rw"
        # the default command to run whenever the container is launched
        command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80
        # the URL 'postgres' or 'mysql' will point to the application's db service
        networks:
          - djangocmsnet
    
        env_file: .env-local
    
      database_default:
        # Select one of the following db configurations for the database
        image: postgres:15-alpine
        ports:
          - "${DB_PORT:-5432}:5432/tcp"  # allow your local dev env to connect to the db if variable set
        environment:
          POSTGRES_DB: "db"
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "password"
          POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: "trust"
          SERVICE_MANAGER: "fsm-postgres"
    
        networks:
          - djangocmsnet
    
        volumes:
           - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    
      frontend:
        # Build the React app from the Dockerfile in the frontend directory
        build: ./frontend
        ports:
          - "3000:80"  # Map React's internal port to 3000 on the host
        volumes:
          - ./frontend:/app
        networks:
          - djangocmsnet
        environment:
          - WDS_SOCKET_HOST=127.0.0.1 
          - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
          - WATCHPACK_POLLING=true 
    
    networks:
      djangocmsnet:
    
    volumes:
      postgres-data:

Build output
[+] Building 71.9s (18/18) FINISHED                                                                                                                                                            
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 37B                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/nginx:alpine                                                                                                                           1.1s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:16-alpine                                                                                                                         1.1s
 => [auth] library/node:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => [auth] library/nginx:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => CACHED [stage-1 1/2] FROM docker.io/library/nginx:alpine@sha256:2140dad235c130ac861018a4e13a6bc8aea3a35f3a40e20c1b060d51a7efd250                                                      0.0s
 => [build 1/8] FROM docker.io/library/node:16-alpine@sha256:a1f9d027912b58a7c75be7716c97cfbc6d3099f3a97ed84aa490be9dee20e787                                                             0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                         2.5s
 => => transferring context: 3.80MB                                                                                                                                                       2.4s
 => CACHED [build 2/8] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => [build 3/8] COPY package.json ./                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => [build 4/8] COPY yarn.lock ./                                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => [build 5/8] RUN yarn install                                                                                                                                                         50.6s
 => [build 6/8] COPY . ./                                                                                                                                                                 6.0s
 => [build 7/8] RUN which yarn                                                                                                                                                            0.3s 
 => [build 8/8] RUN yarn build                                                                                                                                                           10.4s 
 => [stage-1 2/2] COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html                                                                                                                      0.0s 
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                                                    0.0s 
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                                   0.0s 
 => => writing image sha256:339d21ce951e1ab26ff40136083f8eedae3ead3000a893dd60f36291bb659af9


Normally, in Docker, for all kinds of applications in all languages, you need to rebuild the image to get new code, and you need to delete and recreate the container to use the new image.  You should just use plain Node on your host system without involving Docker if you want a live development environment.


Firstly, why npm, node, yarn all show not found in container
when you exec docker exec frontend-1 sh. Because your container
you based on Multi-stage Docker build. # Stage 1 you used FROM node:16-alpine as build. This include (installed) nodejs
environment, so you can run npm, node . But the second stage # Stage 2 . You used FROM nginx:alpine, meaning it only include
(installed) nginx. So you cannot use node here
To solve real problem for you , like refresh hot reload. you should
use mount directories in you docker-compose and need use a
development stage.


Add more development-stage as dev to Dockerfile:
FROM node:16-alpine as dev
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["yarn", "start"]


-Change docker-compose at frontend service to:
build:
    context: ./frontend
    target: dev  # Use the dev stage
ports:
      - "3000:80" # port for prod
      - "3000:3000" # port for dev

